# Python Youtube API v3 don't return me all the videos in particulars channels

Tags: python, api, python-requests, youtube

I have been trying to learn something about API so I did some calls to YT API. I have the following code:

```
# Import Libraries
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import time
```

```
# KEY
API_KEY = 'MY KEY'
CHANNEL_ID = 'SOME YT CHANNEL'
```

```
def get_video_details(video_id):
        # Segundo call al API
        url_video_stats = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+video_id+'&part=statistics&key='+API_KEY
        response_video_stats = requests.get(url_video_stats).json()

        # Recoleccion de views, likes, dislikes y comentarios de cada video
        view_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
        like_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
        comment_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']
        
        return view_count, like_count, comment_count
```

```
def get_videos(df):
    # Make API call
    pageToken = ''
    while 1: # while 1 is the same as while true. It means loop forever. The only way to stop the loop is to use a break statement.
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='+API_KEY+'&channelId='+CHANNEL_ID+'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&'+pageToken
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        time.sleep(2) # Para evitar que se quede en el loop infinito, esperamos 1 segundo antes de hacer el siguiente llamado.

        # Crear el loop para extraer todos los datos de los videos
        for video in response['items']:
            if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video': # Para asegurarme que el objeto sea un video y no otra cosa
                video_id = video['id']['videoId']
                video_title = video['snippet']['title']
                video_title = str(video_title).replace('&amp;', '')
                upload_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
                upload_date = str(upload_date).split('T')[0]
                
                view_count, like_count, comment_count = get_video_details(video_id)

                '''# Guardando los datos en el DataFrame 'df' vacio que creamos antes
                df = df.append({
                    'video_id' : video_id,
                    'video_title' : video_title,
                    'upload_date' : upload_date,
                    'view_count' : view_count,
                    'like_count' : like_count,
                    #'dislike_count' : dislike_count,
                    'comment_count' : comment_count
                    },
                    ignore_index=True
                )'''
                # Guardamos los datos en el df usando pd.concat:
                df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({
                    'video_id' : video_id,
                    'video_title' : video_title,
                    'upload_date' : upload_date,
                    'view_count' : view_count,
                    'like_count' : like_count,
                    'comment_count' : comment_count
                    },
                    index=[0]
                )])
                
        try:
            if response['nextPageToken'] != None: # Si hay una pagina siguiente, entonces seguimos con el loop
                pageToken = "pageToken=" + response['nextPageToken'] 

        except:
            break
        
    return df
```

```
# Main df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['video_id', 'video_title', 'upload_date', 'view_count', 'like_count', 'comment_count'])

df = get_videos(df)
```

And if I try, for example, this channel: UCaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ I only get 322 videos in the DF, nevertheless the channel has +1000 videos

```
{'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse',
 'etag': 'JkC3s6SSNCamNNEIDoC_IcYw9dY',
 'nextPageToken': 'CDIQAA',
 'regionCode': 'AR',
 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1063, 'resultsPerPage': 50},
 'items': [{ ... }]}
```

I was doing some calls from others channels with less videos and I get all of them, but if the channel has, I don't know, 500+ videos, the built functions don't work very well like you can see...

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video

Source: [Search: list#channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId)

AFAIK `Search: list` endpoint is bugged and always limits its results number to 500.

To consume 100 times less quota, in addition to having a working algorithm consider listing `uploads` playlist videos (the playlist id is the channel id with a `UU` as a prefix instead of `UC`) with [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/712360) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the channel you mentioned (*i.e. `UCaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ`*) and I found:

- Its *uploaded videos* - (*i.e uploads playlist*) contains [*727* videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ).
- The total videos in all its playlists (*excluding the uploads playlist*) contains in total: *625* videos<sup>1</sup>.

Checking your code, my suggestions are:

1. Use [playlist:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ%22%7D) endpoint for get all the playlist a given channel has.
2. Use [playlistitems:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22PLHCPwKwATUgAOw3XilQjgpQOaGyd_atCO%22%7D) endpoint for get all videos inside a playlist - unsing the ***id*** from the [playlist:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ%22%7D) response.
3. Use again the [playlistitems:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ%22%7D) endpoint, but, this time, passing the *uploads playlist id* of the channel. You need to change the value from U**C**aY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ` to U**U**aY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ.

The sum of both videos found on all their playlists and their uploaded videos are 1352 videos<sup>1</sup> - which I assume is the number you're referring to in your question:

Quote:

> And if I try, for example, this channel: UCaY_-ksFSQtTGk0y1HA_3YQ I
> only get 322 videos in the DF, **nevertheless the channel has +1000
> videos**

---

<sup>1</sup> Videos up to date (16/08/2022). This number might change in the future = due to new uploads/changes in their playlists, etc.